# Sending a mail for somebody as an application in Microsoft Graph without a login of that user

Tags: c#, email, microsoft-graph-api

I have started to research how to send a mail with Microsoft Graph, but I'm not sure if my scenario is supported.

I need to send a mail at a certain time from a service for a certain user in our company.
I have an application configured in Azure that has the permission for using the Microsoft Graph to send an mail as a user, delegated or not delegated.

I know how to send a mail through the API with a logged-in user.

Is it possible to do this for a user that isn't logged in  on the machine at that time or didn't provide an accestoken to my backend server ( bearer token)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to do this for a user that isn't logged in on the machine at that time or didn't provide an accestoken to my backend server?

No, you need an access token to access the service on behalf of someone else. There is no way to circumvent that so you can perform actions as a user that hasn't authenticated against the service.

Comment: Okay, now I can rest easy that this is not  possible. Thanks for the response

Comment: To add to Patrick's answer, if your admin has consented to your application's permissions for sending mail, it *is* possible to invoke sendmail as a given user. Rather than the user consenting on behalf of their inbox, the admin can consent on behalf of all user's inboxes in a given tenant. You will need an auth token on behalf of your application and the id of the given user. Then you can make a POST to `~/users/<user id>/sendmail`.

Comment: If it is true, then why there is a "send email as any user" permission in the application permission section on azure ad portal?

Comment: With no token it will get hard to send the mail @ozimax06